# Unexpected `^[[I` shows up when running vim script from command line

Tags: scripting, terminal, vim, mouse

In a shell script, if I source even a trivial vim script this way

```
$ cat ascript 
:q

$ cat test
vim -S ascript -N -u NONE
read
```

This is what I get when I run it:

```
$ bash test
^[[I
```

The `^[[I` output is unexpected and breaks the further logic of my shell script.

Does anyone guess/know the nature of it and a possible way to eliminate that effect?

**upd1**

`zsh test` output is the same, `sh` does not work for other reason.

```
$ zsh test
^[[I

$ sh test
test: 2: read: arg count
```

And just for completeness:

```
"Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct 01 2021 01:51:08)
```

**upd2**

After trying to reproduce on other systems:

A shorter way is

```
vim -c ': quit' ; read
```

which may or may not provide you with some garbage output, `^[[I` is just one of the examples, another possible is `^[[2;2R^[]11;rgb:3838/3b3b/4040^G`.  So the other fact I figured out, the issue is not there if one works in a tmux session.
That made me think towards the matter of vim (mis?)handling the terminal settings.
And indeed changing `TERM` from default `xterm-256color` to `screen-256color` makes the issue resolved, or rather worked around.
To resolve it right way, one probably should find a proper combination of [terminal-options](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#terminal-options).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error on CentOS 7.9 and vim 7.4. Out of curosity, does it work if you try `sh test` or `zsh test`?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your use of `vim`? There may be a better tool for noninteractive use

Comment: This is retrieving of the MRU list by `:browse old` but not interactively, using vim's `redir`.
This is actually done long time ago and works fine excluding for cases like in  this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some terminals, including xterm, can be configured to send applications a [control sequence](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-FocusIn_FocusOut) when the terminal gains or loses focus: `^[[I` when the terminal becomes focused and `^[[O` when the terminal stops being focused. Turn this feature off with the control sequence `^[[?1004l` (under `CSI ? Ps l` in the ctlseqs list), or don't turn it on in the first place (it's off by default), or configure some application (Vim?) not to do it.

`^[[2;2R` is the terminal reporting its color palette (documented under `CSI # R` in the ctlseqs document). This only happens when an application running in the terminal requests it (again presumably Vim in your case). `^[]11;rgb:3838/3b3b/4040^G` is a response to an [OSC query](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands) which again is initiated by an application.

Vim under Debian appears to be configured with mouse support turned on by default, even with `-u NONE`. I think that's the cause of your problem. (I can't reproduce it but I'm not in xterm right now.) I'm not a Vim expert, but I think you can run [`:set ttymouse=`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ttymouse%27) or `:set t_RV=` in Vim to turn it off (this needs to be done during initialization, so in `.vimrc` or in a `-S` script: if done interactively, it's too late).

Note on notation: in this answer, I use `^[` for an escape character (`\033` in `printf`, `$'\e'` in bash or zsh). In the xterm documentation, CSI stands for the two-character sequence `^[[`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `set nottymouse` is not a valid option on my systems, giving `E474: Invalid argument: nottymouse`. I can however work around it similarly with `vim -c  ':set ttytype=screen-256color | :quit ' ; read` and perhaps have to play with this more to figure out a more decent general solution if that posssible at all. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Tagwint Apologies, it would be `set ttymouse=` since that's not a boolean option. Lying about the terminal type has the same effect.

Comment: my late acceptance :)
Thank you!